# How to provide security for elastic search in community version

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to provide security( authentication ) for elastic search.x-pack is unable to provide security for free.Is there any plugins for providing security

Comment: try search guard https://search-guard.com/

Answer (score 0):

No official plugin from Elastic. However, you could set up a reverse proxy like Nginx with basic authentication enabled in front of your Elasticsearch.